# Command line (cmd.exe): how to extract folder's security settings

Tags: command-line, security, windows-server-2003

I'd like to know whether it exist a command to show security settings (group names / level of access not necessary needed) of the folder. I tried to google but no success :D

Thank You all in advance.

Comment: Operating system would be a helpful bit of information, and if you use a *Nix variant - which shell you use, and if windows, do you care of CMD vs Powershell?  Otherwise, people will be shooting in the dark to answer this.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry for insufficient description. I hope it's good enought now.

Comment: @Poistenec - What version of Windows.  There are commands that exist for Windows 7 that don't work on Windows XP.  We need more specific information.

Comment: I am willing to use it on Windows 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`cacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx), [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx), [`xcacls`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754), or [`subinacl`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510) commands in Windows to get or set access controls for files and folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) This would be very useful but command cacls icacls xcacls.. is very hard for RAM in case of more than let's say 100 results (as it also provides replication while checking) and also if often gives me SID as result even if object exist. :/

Answer (score 0):

There is [AccessEnum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx) from Microsoft Windows SysInternals.  It isnt command line based, but it sounds like what you are looking for.

> AccessEnum gives you a full view of your file system and Registry security settings in seconds, making it the ideal tool for helping you for security holes and lock down permissions where necessary

[image]

Comment: It is a very good answer, I appreciate it but I'm working on many customer's servers and they would not allow me to run unapproved program :/ Anyway, I'll save it for future :) thanks

Comment: FYI it is a Microsoft program, so in *theory* it should be a trusted application